# Python ImportError: No module named yahoo_finance

Tags: arduino-uno, python

I am new to the Arduino & Python community. I tried to implement the following project:
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/gatoninja236/yahoo-stock-ticker-0df3c7?ref=platform&ref_id=424_trending__beginner_tutorial&offset=1

I followed all steps but when I run the python code, I get the following message:

```
ImportError: No module named yahoo_finance
```

I tried to install the modules with sudo as well. I what I realized that the path is empty.

```
PYTHONPATH:  []
```

when I run the following script:

```
import os
import sys

try:
user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
except KeyError:
user_paths = []

print "PYTHONPATH: ", user_paths
print "sys.path: ", sys.path
```

Even though I edited the .bashrc and .bash_profile like this

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"
```

Is there something else I can try out?

Comment: Does Python run on Arduino as well?

Comment: Please post here the full output of `pip install yahoo_finance`

Comment: @Icipriani Sorry for not replying. I was caught up. Once I get again a free slot, I will try it again. Sorry again!